# Matriz de ocorrência dos pares ordenados x e y em Python

Tags: python, pandas, matriz, contador, heatmap.js

Olá, tenho um dataframe com as colunas x , y e n, onde n é a quantidade de ocorrência do par ordenado x e y.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'x': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1], 'y': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2]}  

# criar DataFrame  
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
ocorrencia = df.groupby(['x', 'y']).size().sort_values(ascending=False)

ocorrencia_df=ocorrencia.to_frame() 

ocorrencia_df.reset_index(inplace=True) 

ocorrencia_df.columns = [ 'x','y','n'] #nomear as colunas
```

Gostaria de fazer uma matriz assim (coloquei as cores para melhor visualização, onde n é a cor azul, x é amarelo e y é verde), mas não estou conseguindo
[image: matriz resultado]

E depois de pronta pretendo usar o heatmap para destacar qual que teve a maior ocorrência

Desde já ,a gradeço pela ajuda

Comment: Qual o formato da matriz? Uma lista de listas?

Comment: A matriz que ele postou parece muito com um dataframe do pandas com 2 níveis de índice nas linhas e nas colunas.

Answer (score 1):

Para chegar no resultado que você deseja, basta utilizar o método [pivot](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html#pandas.DataFrame.pivot).

Esse método basicamente retorna um dataframe organizado conforme as colunas fornecidas por você.

Exemplo: Seguindo o código a partir do ponto que você parou

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {'x': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1], 'y': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2]}  

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

ocorrencia = df.groupby(['x', 'y']).size().sort_values(ascending=False)

ocorrencia_df=ocorrencia.to_frame() 

ocorrencia_df.reset_index(inplace=True) 

ocorrencia_df.columns = [ 'x','y','n']

print(ocorrencia_df)

# Saída: ocorrencia_df
#    x  y  n
# 0  1  1  2
# 1  1  2  1
# 2  2  2  2
# 3  3  3  1
```

Aplicando o método **pivot** no dataframe resultante, obtemos:

```py
ocorrencia_df = ocorrencia_df.pivot(index='y', columns='x', values='n')

print(ocorrencia_df)
# Saída: ocorrencia_df
# x    1    2    3
# y               
# 1  2.0  NaN  NaN
# 2  1.0  2.0  NaN
# 3  NaN  NaN  1.0
```

Existe outro método bem parecido só que expande ainda mais as possibilidades de se trabalhar com geração de pivô no pandas, é o [pivot_table](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html#pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table). Recomendo a leitura dos dois métodos, pode ajudar você futuramente em muitas coisas.

**Referências**:

1. https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html#pandas.DataFrame.pivot
2. https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html#pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table